# Customize the Sign in with Apple button in iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-sign-in

Is the "Sign in with Apple" button customizable at all in an iOS project using Objective-C?

Answer (score 0):

if you take a look at the documentation ([Sign In with Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/asauthorizationappleidbutton)) you will se that you can customise it, but only colour, corner radius, and no much more...
can you explain what do you want to do exactly? maybe we can help!

Comment: Need to modify the fontsize, icon spacing